# How to rearrange pinned taskbar icons without a mouse in Win 7 Pro?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Is there a way to reorder my pinned icons using keyboard shortcuts or an external app?  I don't have a mouse and I want to rearrange them in a specific order without using a mouse to drag!

Win 7 Pro.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it starts with `Win`+`U`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any built-in keyboard shortcuts for rearranging the taskbar icons. However, you can use an accessibility feature called MouseKeys to effectively accomplish the same thing, albeit with a bit more work.

To enable MouseKeys, open the Start menu, type in `mousekeys` and click on what should be the only result. Alternatively, hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open the Ease of Access Center, and click on "Make the keyboard easier to use".

In the new window that opens, check the "Turn on Mouse Keys" option and hit Apply. Or if you're trying to do this part without the mouse as well, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to check that option (it should be active already, or move around with <kbd>Tab</kbd> if it isn't), and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to Apply the settings.

Now you can use your numeric keyboard to move the mouse pointer around. To move the taskbar icons around, move the pointer to the icon you want to move and hit <kbd>0</kbd> (this simulates pressing and holding the left mouse button). Then move the icon to the new location and hit <kbd>.</kbd> (to release the mouse button).
Note: that's the number zero (not the letter "O"), and the decimal point key. MouseKeys only uses numpad keys.

More information on how to use MouseKeys, including all the numpad keys and their functions, is available in [this Microsoft help article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer).

Comment: After 0 is that a "period button"?

Comment: Zero or the letter "O"?  Doesn't work...moved the pointer on top of the pinned icon but nothing happens!

Comment: Hee, oh the zero within the mouse keys. Works. I was lost first cause the no. 5 simulates the left-mouse button for me too!

Comment: @verve It's zero, and the decimal point key. MouseKeys only uses keys on the numeric keypad. I'll amend my answer to include this.

Comment: @verve Number 5 simulates a click, while 0 simulates click-and-hold.